# How to express time window function with SQL for Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple `DataFrame`, whose schema is:

```
word: string
process_time: timestamp
```

I group by then time window and count on the grouped `DataFrame`:

```
val windowedCount = wordsDs
  .groupBy(
    window($"processing_time", "15 seconds")
  ).count()
```

How can I port this code to SQL, using Spark SQL's syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty much one-to-one translation:

```
spark.sql("""SELECT window(process_time, "15 seconds"), count(*) 
             FROM wordDs 
             GROUP BY window(process_time, "15 seconds")""")
```

or:

```
spark.sql("""WITH tmp AS(SELECT window(process_time, "15 seconds") w FROM wordDs)
             SELECT w, count(*) FROM tmp GROUP BY w""")
```